# MS Teams create a html tab

Tags: html, configuration, microsoft-teams

MS teams has a way to create a configuration page as a tab which will create a iframe where we can embed deep links in that. Can anyone suggest me a way to do this.

If i create a website as a tab it is downloading the page everytime i click on that.

Comment: Please have a look at [Tab documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/tabs/tabs-overview). Let us know if you are looking for something specific.

Comment: I am not able to find the steps to do that

Comment: Here is step by step guide for [C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/get-started/get-started-dotnet-app-studio) & [Node](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/get-started/get-started-nodejs-app-studio). Let me know if this helps, I'll add this as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at [Tab documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/tabs/tabs-overview) for details about configurable tabs.

Here is step by step guide for [C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/get-started/get-started-dotnet-app-studio) & [Node](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/get-started/get-started-nodejs-app-studio).